# Angular Reactive Forms - Adding controls during patchValue - is that safe?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Let's say I have a form group

```
group = this.formBuilder.group({
    optionTrueFalse: [null]
})
```

Then I have a valueChange subscription that adds a control or removes it based on `optionTrueFalse`:

```
group.controls.optionTrueFalse.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (!!value) {
        group.addControl('explain', new formControl(''));
    }
    else {
        group.removeControl('explain');
    }
}
```

Now I patch the following values:

```
group.patchValue({
    optionTrueFalse: true,
    explain: 'Just Because'
});
```

Right now in Angular version 7.2.6 it works fine. Question is: Is this reliable and safe?

Docs say:

> patchValue()
>
> > Patches the value of the FormGroup. It accepts an object with control names as keys, and ***does its best*** to match the values to the correct controls in the group.

Not sure what it means by 'does its best'.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ed4675e5a1fa3a570c652804994831c43b7cda1a/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1409), I see:

```
patchValue(value: {[key: string]: any}, options: {onlySelf?: boolean, emitEvent?: boolean} = {}):void {
    Object.keys(value).forEach(name => {
      if (this.controls[name]) {
        this.controls[name].patchValue(value[name], {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: options.emitEvent});
      }
    });
    this.updateValueAndValidity(options);   
}
```

Theoretically if `Object.keys` give the sames order as I give (a little vague on MDN) then it should work. I just want to know what others have to say and how it will play out in the future?